# search XML for string recursively and return XML tag names

Tags: xml, vbscript, hta

I am trying to search for a string in my XML document and want to return its ancestor tag names to track it down.

Currently in my code I enter the XML path and string and return tag names by `echo`ing it.

But I want some modifications to it:

1. I want user to select directory and code should process all XML files in directory.
2. Code should search for all occurrence of the text in XML file.
3. It should return information in readable format like a tabular format for string, and containing tag names.

My current code is given below that has text value and XML path hardcoded and it echoes each tag name.

```vb
Dim oFS      : Set oFS      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sFSpec   : sFSpec       = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("xyz.xml")
Dim objMSXML : Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
objMSXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
objMSXML.async = False
objMSXML.load sFSpec

If 0 = objMSXML.parseError Then
   Dim sXPath   : sXPath       =  "//*[local-name()='namespace']/*[local-name()='querySubject']/*[local-name()='queryItem'][contains(., 'SearchTerm')]/ancestor-or-self::*/*[local-name()='name']"

   '//namespace//querySubject/queryItem[contains(.,'searchTerm')]/ancestor-or-self::*/name    
   Dim querySubject : Set querySubject = objMSXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
   If querySubject Is Nothing Then
      WScript.Echo sXPath, "failed"
   Else
      For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
         WScript.Echo node.text
      Next
   End If
Else
   WScript.Echo objMSXML.parseError.reason
End If
```

Sample XML is:

```xml
<project xmlns = "https://afdsl/skdflsk/d">
  <name>Abcpos</name>
  <property name="included" type="hidden">true</property>
  <locales>
    <locale>en</locale>
    <locale>de</locale>
  </locales>
  <defaultLocale>en</defaultLocale>
  <namespace>
    <name locale="en">Abcpos</name>
    <name locale="de">Abcpos</name>
    <lastChanged>2015-04-06T17:37:40</lastChanged>
    <lastChangedBy>userx</lastChangedBy>
    <property name="included" type="hidden">true</property>
    <namespace>
      <name locale="en">Database Layer</name>
      <querySubject status="valid">
      <name locale="en">qskxyz</name>
      <queryItem>
        <name locale="en">qixyz</name>
          <hello>searchTerm</hello>
        </queryItem>
      </querySubject>
    </namespace>
  </namespace>
  <namespace>
    <name locale="en">Names</name>
    <lastChanged>2016-01-12T12:42:46</lastChanged>
    <namespace>
      <name locale="en">Database Layer</name>
      <querySubject status="valid">
      <name locale="en">qsxyz</name>
      <queryItem>
        <name locale="en">myName</name>
          <hello>...Hi there..</hello>
        </queryItem>
      </querySubject>
    </namespace>
  </namespace>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list the parent node names of all nodes containing user-provided text anywhere in your XML you could simply use something like this:

```vb
xpath = "//*[contains(.,'" & searchtext & "')]/.."
For Each node In objMSXML.SelectNodes(xpath)
     WScript.Echo node.NodeName
Next
```

As for processing all XML files in a directory, there are tons of examples for this here on SO and elsewhere.